# Stopped due to shared library event while debugging WSL on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm getting

```
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
```

On VSCode when trying to debug my C project on WSL.

I've got the following `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/mnt/c/Coding/tau-cs-projects/chessproj/bin/chessprog",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "/mnt/c/Coding/tau-cs-projects/chessproj",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeCwd": "",
                "pipeProgram": "c:\\windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe",
                "pipeArgs": ["-c"],
                "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/mnt/c": "c:\\"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and my makefile contains the following:

```
...
CC              := gcc
CFLAGS          := -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -g
SDLINC_NOVA     := -I/usr/local/lib/sdl_2.0.5/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
SDLLIB_NOVA     := -L/usr/local/lib/sdl_2.0.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/sdl_2.0.5/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
...
```

Furthermore, I'm able to debug "manually" with `gdb` (from the terminal).
What is the cause for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem which happened when executing getaddrinfo(ipAddress,...)
It turned out that the problem was caused by ipAddress being passed as a quoted string instead of just a string. Instead of just returning an error, the gdb session aborted with the "Stopped due to library event" error message.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the cause for this?

Something in VSCode did `(gdb) set stop-on-solib-events 1` (I have no idea where that setting is coming from).

You can undo this with `(gdb) set stop-on-solib-events 0`.

Comment: I'm getting `Unable to perform this action because the process is running.`

Comment: where to run this `(gdb) set stop-on-solib-events 0` ? command prompt?